# dot.js working with array

Tags: javascript, dot.js

I have a problem working with dot when I have template like this

```
{{=it.data[0].visitors}}
```

so this doesn't work

```
var data = [{
  visitors: 10
}];

var tempFn = doT.template("<h1>Here is a sample template {{=it.data[0].visitors}}</h1>");

var resultText = tempFn(data[0]);
```

Comment: if you change last line with `var resultText = tempFn(data);` ?

Comment: still not working, here is an example
http://jsfiddle.net/VGwqK/367/

Answer (score 0):

You need to name what you insert as template vars :

http://jsfiddle.net/0ds9rfk1/

```
var tempFn = doT.template("<h1>Here is a sample template {{=it.data.visitors}}</h1>");
var resultText = tempFn({data:data[0]});
```

or

```
var tempFn = doT.template("<h1>Here is a sample template {{=it.data[0].visitors}}</h1>");
var resultText = tempFn({data});
```

Comment: so for your post this last line should work `var resultText = tempFn({data});`